# why using a template as a parameter in the STL map template is refused?

Tags: c++, class, templates, dictionary, stl

I wrote this little code

```
std::map<int,template<class T>> map_;
map_.insert(make_pair<int,message>(myMsg.id,myMsg));
```

but the compiler doesn't seem to get it and displays as an error

```
template argument 2 is invalid
```

and when I tried to correct by doing this

```
template<class T>
std::map<int,T> map_;
```

it displays as an error :

> expected primary-expression before 'template' |
>
> error: expected ';' before 'template'

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Note that templates must always be resolved at compile-time. It seems you want to build a polymorphic container with them, which is not possible; you must use virtual inheritance for that.

Comment: well actually I'm supposed to store different kind of message each type in a map , so I tried to make a global structure by calling it by "std::map<int,template<class T> > map_;" (which doesn't work neither) so class could be message_typeA, message_typeB, etc

Comment: As I said, that's not possible this way. Make `message_typeA`, `message_typeB` derived classes of `messegetype_base`, then you can use a container with e.g. `std::unique_ptr`s to any of these objects. It's a bit more complicated than in dynamic languages (or at least garbage-collected ones), but it does have its benefits (compile-time type safety, good performance...).

Comment: so can I make a container with messagetype_base then when creating the objects I use messagetype_base myMsg= new message_typeA() ??

Comment: Almost. It has to be a container with _pointers_ to `messagetype_base`, it is for safety and convenience reasons that I would recommend `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: why std::unique_ptr specifically ? what's wrong with a std::auto_ptr or even boost::shared_ptr !

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_Smart_Pointers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but you are trying to declare a variable, and that definition has to be fully defined. Trying to use a template doesn't fully define the variable.

You can wrap it in a structure if you want to:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    typedef std::map<int, T> map_type;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
Wrapper<std::string>::map_type my_wrapped_map;
my_wrapped_map[1] = "Foo";
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked well but I tried to add another field to this struct " typedef  std::map<int,T >::iterator  map_type_iter; " but it displayed an error and I can't get what's wrong with it !

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using a C++11 compiler, and this line is invalid:

```
std::map<int,template<class T>> map_;
```

It should be

```
std::map<int,template<class T> > map_;
```

Notice the space between `> >`. Pre-C++11, `>>` is always treated as the bit shift operator.

Besides this, what is the code supposed to do? If I'm not mistaken, you should declare your map as

```
std::map<int,message> map_;
```

Now, `std::map<int,template<class T>> map_;` doesn't really make sense, unless this is a member of another template class, in which case you need

```
std::map<int,T> map_;
```

Comment: how do I know which compiler I'm currently using ?? is there any command I need to run ?? btw I'm using codeblocks as an IDE which includes the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from MinGW.

Answer (score -1):

```
define KEYINT_MAP(T) std::map<int, T>
KEYINT_MAP(class) map;
```